# Is there a Polymer web component for Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: polymer, google-sheets

I'm looking for documentation/usage that encapsulates querying a sheet in drive.

I know you can load in a published sheet using  as given in this article: "[Building Web Apps with Yeoman and Polymer](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/yeoman/)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a web component based on Polymer: https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-sheets

Docs for the web component are here: http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-sheets/components/google-sheets/

For more web components, take a look at these sites: http://customelements.io/ and http://component.kitchen/